# I need a ritual to review memories

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

Is there a ritual already that can do this? If not, can someone please suggest a level and other mechanics to make it work?

The ritual should allow the caster to review the target’s memories from over a period of time (ideally established by the roll or sets a dc). The quality of the memories is determined by how much the person recalls of events, though the caster may effectively ‘ask questions’ of the memories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Speak with Dead (perhaps renamed to speak with memories or summon psyche or something) as a starting point would seem very reasonable.

Comment: This seems exactly right to me.  It could even be a little easier to cast, meaning either a lower lever, lower DCs, or a lower component cost.  It seems that reviewing the memories of a living person should be easier than doing it to a dead person.

Comment: Speak with Dead is level 6. So at 6 or down to 5? If I lower the level then lower the DCs by 2 pts?

Comment: Number balance is definitely not my thing, but level 5 with 2pt lower DCs seems about right to me.

Comment: You may want to actually leave the DC, or increase it - or at least, increase it due to certain conditions such as character class, origin, or race.  While on its face, it may seem that recalling memories from a living person should be easier than from a dead person, remember that living people - and I expect this would especially apply to Psionic or Arcane masters - can actively resist this whereas the dead have no choice.

Answer (score 2):

The level 11 ritual, [History Revealed](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=221) from Arcane Power might make a better choice.

> When you complete the ritual, you touch a willing or
>   helpless creature and see the most defining moments
>   of the creature's life.

What you seen are 'Scenes'.  You have access to 1 (arcana check of 9 or lower) to 5 scenes (arcana check of 40+).